# How to calculate number of hours of sleep for each record

Tags: sas

I have a data set for every kid and when each kids go to the bed and when they wake up in the morning. I want to calculate the number of hours of sleep

Below is the just a sample data:

```
id          time1(kids go bed)          time2(kids wake up time)   
101        12:00(am)                    5:00(pm)    
102        3:00(am)                    9:30(am)    
103        7:00(pm)                    6:00(am)    
104        4:15(am)                    2:00(pm)
```

As you can observe I have the different time combination for ex:they go to bed at early morning(AM) and they wake up late afternoon next day(PM).

Let  me know if you have any question?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  With StackOverflow you are expected to try and solve the problem yourself first and show what you have tried and explain what problems you are having.

Comment: convert to 24 hour time and subtract. but seriously, this question is going to get closed if you don't take the time to properly explain what you are trying to accomplish and give better examples. and as the above said, show what you have tried or are currently struggling with.

Comment: i want to use SAS language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to create a new column named `SleepHour` based on when the kids go to bed and when they wake up.

Use you data, then `SleepHour = Time2 - Time1`.Suppose both `time2` and `time1` are in `datetime` format.

```
data WANT;
set HAVE;
SleepHour = (Time2 - Time1)/3600; /* seconds to hours */
run;
```

But I guess the raw data may only contains the `time` part without `date` part. So you need to clarify how you want to calculate the `no. of hours`.

Well let's assume kids won't sleep over 24 hrs per day. Then you need a `if` condition to calculate `no of hours`.

```
data WANT;
set HAVE;
if hour(time2) ge hour(time1) then SleepHour = (Time2 - Time1)/3600; 
else SleepHour = (Time2 + 24*3600 - Time1)/3600; 
run;
```